# An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I am running PHP 5.3.24 (XAMPP package) and Microsoft SQL Server Express 2012 on windows 7 ultimate.

I have created a form to create a question bank for multiple choice tests.  When I try to submit a question, I get the following error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14
>   [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.
>   [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )

Here's the code I use in the PHP file that handles the post data from the form:

```
<?PHP
//section 1: define variables from post and clean up for posting.
$Question = $_POST['Question'];
$Question = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Question)));
$Answer1 = $_POST['Answer1'];
$Answer1 = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Answer1)));
$Answer2 = $_POST['Answer2'];
$Answer2 = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Answer2)));
$Answer3 = $_POST['Answer3'];
$Answer3 = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Answer3)));
$Answer4 = $_POST['Answer4'];
$Answer4 = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Answer4)));
$Answer5 = $_POST['Answer5'];
$Answer5 = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Answer5)));
$Answer6 = $_POST['Answer6'];
$Answer6 = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Answer6)));
$Answer7 = $_POST['Answer7'];
$Answer7 = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Answer7)));
$Answer8 = $_POST['Answer8'];
$Answer8 = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Answer8)));
$Answer9 = $_POST['Answer9'];
$Answer9 = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Answer9)));
$Answer10 = $_POST['Answer10'];
$Answer10 = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $Answer10)));
$QuestionNotes = $_POST['QuestionNotes'];
$QuestionNotes = trim(stripslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $QuestionNotes)));
$CorrectAnsw = $_POST['CorrectAnsw'];
$ProgramArea = $_POST['ProgramArea'];
$Difficulty = $_POST['Difficulty'];

//section 2: define sql statement
$sql=   ("INSERT INTO TESTDB.dbo.tblTestQuestions 
                (Question,Answer1,Answer2,Answer3,Answer4,Answer5, 
                 Answer6,Answer7,Answer8,Answer9,Answer10,CorrectAnsw,
                 ProgramArea,Difficulty,QuestionNotes,Inactive) 

        VALUES
                    (   '" . $Question . "','" . $Answer1 . "','" . $Answer2 . "','" . $Answer3 . "','" . $Answer4 . "',
                        '" . $Answer5 . "','" . $Answer6 . "','" . $Answer7 . "','" . $Answer8 . "','" . $Answer9 . "',
                        '" . $Answer10 . "'," . $CorrectAnsw . "," . $ProgramArea . "," . $Difficulty . ",
                        '" . $QuestionNotes . "',0)"); 

//section 3: call db connnection and post to database
include('C:/webincludes/dbconnect.php');    //this include defines $conn and has been tested to work
                                            //fine and I use it on dozens of other forms that work fine.

if (!SQLSRV_query($conn,$sql))
  {die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));} echo "Record Added";

SQLSRV_close($conn);


//section 4:    I added the following to display the variables to see what is being passed to the sql server.
//              To use it, I comment out section 3 and try to submit again.
echo "
        <html><body><br><font face='calibri' size='5'><b>Output as follows: </font></b><br>
        Question:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $Question . "<br>
        Ans1:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   " . $Answer1 . "<br>
        Ans2:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   " . $Answer2 . "<br>
        Ans3:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   " . $Answer3 . "<br>
        Ans4:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   " . $Answer4 . "<br>
        Ans5:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   " . $Answer5 . "<br>
        Ans6:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   " . $Answer6 . "<br>
        Ans7:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   " . $Answer7 . "<br>
        Ans8:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   " . $Answer8 . "<br>
        Ans9:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   " . $Answer9 . "<br>
        Ans10:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    " . $Answer10 . "<br>
        Correct Answ:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   " . $CorrectAnsw . "<br>
        Area:   " . $ProgramArea . "<br>
        Level:  " . $Difficulty . "<br>
        Notes:  " . $QuestionNotes . "<br>
        <b>SQL Statement:</b><br>
        " . $sql . "<br>
        " . $stmt . "<br>
        </font></body></html>
        ";

exit;
?>
```

When I submit data, I get the error above.  If I comment out section 3 which actually runs the SQL script, and just post the data to display it, I get the following:

> Output as follows: 
>
> Question:    What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow
> Ans1:       43 bp
> Ans2:       what do you mean? african or european?
> Ans3:       Blue, no yellooooooooooooooooow
> Ans4:       a shrubbery!
> Ans5:       Ni!
> Ans6:       Great Peril!
> Ans7:       Robins minsterals
> Ans8:       your mother was a hamster and your father smelt of elderberries.
> Ans9:       its only a model
> Ans10:      message for you, sir!
> Correct Answ:    :  2
> Area:   10
> Level:  3
> Notes:  we are the knights who say... Ni!
> SQL Statement:
>
> INSERT INTO CAR.dbo.tblTestQuestions (Question,Answer1,Answer2,Answer3,Answer4,Answer5, Answer6,Answer7,Answer8,Answer9,Answer10,CorrectAnsw, ProgramArea,Difficulty,QuestionNotes,Inactive) VALUES ( 'What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow','43 bpm','what do you mean? african or european?','Blue, no yellooooooooooooooooow','a shrubbery!', 'Ni!','Great Peril!','Robins minsterals','your mother was a hamster and your father smelt of elderberries.','its only a model', 'message for you, sir!',2,10,3, 'we are the knights who say... Ni!',0)

If I take that sql statement and run it through the management console, it inserts the data just fine.  But when I try to run it from the webpage, error.

I'm confounded.  Please forgive a newb, but where am I going wrong?

Comment: can't see any issues. Are you sure the table you're trying to insert to exists and has the fields you're trying to insert?

Comment: Yes. In section 4 I set it to output the actual insert statement at the end. I have copied and pasted this insert statement into the SQL management studio, so I know that's what is being passed to SQL, and it inserts just fine.  I can run a select and see it in there. Very odd.

Comment: Ok so if that query is running in SQL server then the issue is with the connection, do you have any if(!$conn){ die('cannot connect');}

Comment: Ok, now I feel like a moron... typo in the connection code in the include.  I didn't expect it would give me the invalid parameter message.  Thanks for the help - it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: all good, it happens :)